# How to set user commands in TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio

I installed TexStudio in my Mac and now I want to set a user command. That command should run one `.bat` file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a user defined tool. Open the preferences and go to build. In the lower part of the window you can add user commands. If you make sure that your batch file is executable it should work if you add the path and name as command.
The new macro then is available via Tool > User or you can assign a short cut in the preferences.

See section [1.3 in the manual](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a).