# Setting up LaTeX -> DVIPS -> PS2PDF with Shell-Escape (in TeXStudio)

Tags: texstudio, shell-escape

I am trying to set up a "user command" on `TeXStudio` with the purpose of compiling with `shell-escape` and the `LaTeX -> DviPs -> Ps2Pdf` cycle.

This is what I have done to get `shell-escape` to work and produce `PDF` output. [**Edit:** This section edited: see explanation below]

**Method 1.** In `TeXStudio` preferences -> `Build` -> `User Commands`:

```
latexmk --shell-escape
latexmk -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

See screenshot: top user command, the two lines above are entered from left to right.

[image]

**Method 2.** At the top of my document insert the line:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
```

This line induces `TeXStudio` to request authorization to compile with `shell-escape`. This setup has so far worked for me to invoke `shell-escape` *and* produce `PDF` output "on the fly".

By **analogy**, I tried the following:

**Method 1b.** User Command:

```
latex --shell-escape: dvips : ps2pdf : view-pdf
latex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex: dvips -o %.ps %.dvi: ps2pdf %.ps
```

**Method 2b.** Top of document:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///latex/[--shell-escape]
```

But that does not work. Am I on the right track?

To provide context: my purpose is to be able to compile the code shown here: [Recreating a guilloche with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46507/recreating-a-guilloche-with-tikz). The code relies on the `tkz-fct` package and apparently requires the use of `shell-escape` but does not support `pdflatex`, suggesting that the `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` route is a natural one to try. And it is the route recommended in the `tkz-fct` manual.

[How to set user commands in TexStudio?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135132/how-to-set-user-commands-in-texstudio) is a tex-stackexchange question with a link to the `TeXStudio` doc, which addresses related problems, but not this particular one head-on.

The `TeXStudio` documentation is here:

http://svn.code.sf.net/p/texstudio/code/trunk/utilities/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a

**Edit:** Explanation about my first edit. I initially wrote that I had been succesful with the following settings:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

However, I had been running this command on documents that had this at the top:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
```

And it turns out that this line overrules my user commands. This is stated explicitly in Harish Kumar's answer (thanks Harish!). Without this overruling line, my user command does not succesfully invoke `shell-escape`. However, replacing `pdflatex` with `latexmk` did invoke `shell-escape` without the overruling line. I have therefore edited my incorrect claim. Having said that, I do not know much about `latexmk` other than it seems to be working.

**Epilogue:** Read Harish Kumar's answer to see how to properly enter the commands. Another thing I have since discovered is that the spanner-shaped button allows you to select among existing commands and to combine several commands, in that way the proper separator will be added between commands. Lastly, if you read the various comments here you will see that one reason why I had a hard time getting this to work was because the LaTeX file I was trying to compile needs `gnuplot` and I didn't have `gnuplot` installed on my system, giving me the impression that my commands were not working when they were (after Harish's corrections they were working properly).

Comment: Patrick, `latexmk --shell-escape` in the first box is just a name for the user command. It has nothing more to do. What you type in the second box is the executable command. So in first box you can type any name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the line

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///latex/[--shell-escape]
```

at the top of the document, then you don't need any extra user command. Just compile it. Then texstudio will compile it with `latex` with `--shell-escape` (of course it will ask your permission) (even if the default build has `pdflatex` as the compiler) and `dvi` file is produced. Then you can run `DVI2PS` and in turn `PS2PDF`.

Now the question is - whether you would like to compile the document with *three* clicks or *one* click. If the latter, then define a new user command like the following:

1. Type the name of the command in the first box (mine is `user2: LaTex.DVIPS.PS2PDF`) ( `(user2:` may be different for you).
2. Type the command:

   ```
   latex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex | dvips -o %.ps %.dvi| ps2pdf %.ps
   ```

in the second box as in this picture:

[image]

Note that command separator is `|`, not `:`.

Now if you use `user2: LaTex.DVIPS.PS2PDF` to compile, you won't need that first line: `% !TeX TXS-p...`.

I get this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't work for me. I have the latest version of TeXStudio and am on Mac OS X. Two questions, if I may: 1) There are 2 boxes, do you mind detailing what you have in each? I'm assuming the line you have above is for the second box, so what about the first box? 2) do you have `% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///latex/[--shell-escape]` at the top of your document?  I don't get any pdf produced, and I don't get the message `entering extended mode`. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickT Your first box is wrong. See the update.

Comment: thanks, that's very thorough, great answer. Well, I must have something wrong in my system. I notice from the first user command that you're on Windows and MikTeX. I'm on Mac OS and TeXLive. Perhaps a difference there. I'll test your lines on Windows and Linux tomorrow and get back to you (it's bed time in my time zone). Thanks again!

Comment: @PatrickT Now I am on windows, but for texstudio and its macros, it shouldn't make any difference :) Good night

Comment: I'm still on the case ... I had other stuff to do today ;-) Now what I have discovered is that my `latexmk --shell-escape` profile generates the message `entering extended mode` and `\write18 enabled` whereas the `pdflatex --shell-escape` or `latex --shell-escape` commands generate `entering extended mode` and `restricted \write18 enabled`. So maybe a difference there. The other thing is that when I compile the `guilloché` code, there is a reference to `gnuplot` which I don't have on my Mac OS X (no mention of gnuplot in the manual)... I'm going to try on Windows and Linux right now.

Comment: I've now tested extensively on Windows 7 and am observing the same behaviour as Mac OS X: My user commands seem to work in that they compile ordinary documents. Note 1: no `usr2:` in front of the command, otherwise it fails. Note 2: `shell-escape` is invoked in **restricted** mode (whatever that means) for `pdflatex`  and `latex` and in full mode for `latexmk`. The `guilloché` code doesn't run, but the error message is pretty explicit about a `gnuplot` problem. Now I'll try on linux, where I do have gnuplot. (had to update for >4 hours my Windows + tlmgr, I hadn't been there a while!)

Comment: @PatrickT: `user2:` is generated by texstudio itself.

Comment: thanks! Well, now I've managed to make it work on Linux, where I have gnuplot and lots of other stuff installed, so my suspicion is that I'm missing something crucial on my Windows and Mac setups: does gnuplot need to be installed (I saw nothing about that in the manual)? I have also been able to add the `usr0:` in front of the command, and I suspect the problem was a space I might have added between `usr` and the number. So that was a silly move on my part. Do you know something about `gnuplot`? I'd say my question has been answered, and thanks again!

Comment: @PatrickT For the guilloche code, you will need `gnuplot` installed. Install it on windows too and it should work. Glad you could make it :)

Comment: I have posted instructions on how to install gnuplot on Mac OS X here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71160/how-to-use-gnu-plot-to-plot-diagrams-in-texshop?lq=1

I haven't tried on Windows yet, but since I have it on Linux in another partition on the same laptop I don't think I will bother to try on Windows now ;-)