# Feynmp-auto: why is the diagram not included in the pdf file?

Tags: diagrams, miktex, shell-escape, feynmf, feynmp-auto

When trying to draw a Feynman diagram using the `feynmp-auto` package, there simply is no result, the pdf comes out as a blank page. I use TeXstudio and MikTeX, and run the file with `pdflatex`.

I have read the [documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/feynmp-auto/feynmp-auto.pdf) (in which it is stated that in the case one uses MikTeX, `-shell-espace` should be used) and have tried to force TeXstudio to run with `-shell-escape` in multiple ways (exhausted the options in [Setting up LaTeX -> DVIPS -> PS2PDF with Shell-Escape (in TeXStudio)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160648/setting-up-latex-dvips-ps2pdf-with-shell-escape-in-texstudio)).

The MWE that I'm trying to run is the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\unitlength=1mm
\begin{fmffile}{photon}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
        \fmfkeep{photon}
        \fmfleft{i1,i2}
        \fmfright{o1,o2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,i2}
        \fmf{fermion}{o1,v2,o2}
        \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

How does one get the diagram to show up in the pdf?

Comment: Did you compile twice? Two runs of LaTeX are necessary when there's a new diagram in the document (or we're at the first run).

Comment: @egreg Yes. The file photon.mp is created in the first run (and probably overwritten in the second), and should thus be available for inclusion in the second run.

Comment: `photon.mp` is not what's included, but `photon.1`, which is obtained when `photon.mp` is processed by Metapost. Remove all the `photon.*` files and retry, or try `\usepackage[force]{feynmp-auto}`

Comment: I've done both deleting the `photon.*` files and using `\usepackage[force]{feynmp-auto}` now, but no result. Does this mean Metapost isn't run?

Comment: I think so. Sorry, but I can't test on MiKTeX.

Comment: @egreg It does work (oh, finally) when including `-shell-escape` in the pdflatex command line, but the pdf file is not created when writing `% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///latex/[-shell-escape]` in the document. Apparently these are not equivalent.