# Setting up TeXstudio to run LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf

Tags: texstudio, dvips, ps2pdf

I am trying to obtain nice Matlab figures in my LaTeX report and although there are many ways to achieve this, a lot of them don't work for my large data plots.

But using LaPrint gets me nice graphical results but I have a problem with my labels. They are all shown like:

```
s06,s05,x01,x02,..etc
```

I localized the problem in the fact that my TeXstudio invokes `pdflatex` where it should invoke `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`. How do I properly set that up? I did like this following [latex-dvips-ps2pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160648/setting-up-latex-dvips-ps2pdf-with-shell-escape-in-texstudio)

I added a user command as follows:

```
user0: LaTex.DVIPS.PS2PDF
latex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex | dvips -o %.ps %.dvi| ps2pdf %.ps
```

and set that as default compiler command

```
DefaultCompiler
user0:LaTex.DVIPS.PS2PDF
```

Error:

```
Could not start the command: user0:LaTex.DVIPS.PS2PDF
```

---

Hack:

If you set the latex command to:

latex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex | dvips -o %.ps %.dvi| ps2pdf %.ps

it works, only it is an ugly solution since you are inserting other commands dvips and ps2pdf into the latex command.

Comment: Hope the edited title is OK (if not, do change it), it seems like my suggestion more accurately describes the problem.

Comment: Thankyou, that is indeed a better description. Halfway trough my posting I learned something that made the question a bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the only error in the first solution was the naming of the default compiler.

You should call `txs:///user0` there.

The naming pattern for user commands is `<command id>:<display name>` [see the manual](http://file:///C:/Users/Tim/Documents/texstudio/texstudio-hg/utilities/manual/usermanual_en.html#SECTION02a). In your case (`user0:LaTex.DVIPS.PS2PDF`), `user0` is the id, "LaTex.DVIPS.PS2PDF" is used for the label in the Tools menu.