# Set programmatically latex+dvips+ps2pdf at the beginning of the document with TeXStudio

Tags: texstudio, eps, animate, epstopdf, epslatex

Bearing in mind that have to change buttons back and forth between `pdflatex` and `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` is very time consuming, as  `pdflatex` main compiler

Is there any way to set programmatically `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` at the beggining of the document in order to avoid this process of changing buttons?

[image]

For example, it is possible to have PdfLaTeX as main compiler and have it changed issuing the following command at the beginning:

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
```

[image]

I am trying this, but does not work as expected with the buttons:

```
% !TeX program = latex
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///user0
```

where user0 is the following user command:

```
user0: LaTex.DVIPS.PS2PDF
latex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex | dvips -o %.ps %.dvi | ps2pdf %.ps
```

[image]

[Setting up TeXstudio to run LaTeX + dvips + ps2pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223286/setting-up-texstudio-to-run-latex-dvips-ps2pdf)